# Publish Laravel Project from a Subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

Laravel is designed to serve at the root directory unless some tweaks are done as you all know.

I have a Laravel project which I used to run it on the server's `public_html` folder. Then I decided to move it to a subfolder `folder1`.

What I want to happen is to see the laravel page at `www.example.com/folder1` instead of `www.example.com`.

I have created a `.htaccess` file inside `folder1`. and wrote some redirect rules:

```
#file: /folder1/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/public/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    #since it doesn't show the page I had to redirect the route 
    #to the public folder, which is another subject.

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder1/public/$1
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ folder1/public/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Still I got the 404 error but this error does not come from the server, from Laravel. Then I have changed the routes in **web.php** in **routes** folder.

For example:

```
//FROM
Route::get('/categories', function () {
    return view('categories');
});

Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

//TO:
Route::get('/folder1/categories', function () {
    return view('categories');
});

Route::get('/folder1/login', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});
```

It is working now but I am worrying if it is a good solution? What could I have done instead?

Comment: Do you have access to your terminal? full access to your webhost or are you on a shared hosting?

Comment: @KGG unfortunately no

Comment: Oh that is sad, I was going to post a solution where you can just delete the `public_html` folder and do a symlink between your laravel `public` folder to `public_html` then `ln -s /home/yoursite/laravel/public /home/yoursite/public_html` and just avoid .htaccess/redirects entirely :(

Comment: on side note you can simplify the routes like `Route::view('/categories', 'categories');` if they are simply returning a view instead of calling the controller.